# A table that shows MySql data, which the user can edit

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, user-interface

I'm working on a C# application and need to give the users a user-friendly environment to work in. The idea is that a user uses his/her id and password so only data relevant to the user will show up in a table. I've figured out how to do this but now the user needs to be able to edit the contents of the table and since it's all about giving the user that friendly looking interface.

What table-like component should I use to achieve this? I need to be able to load in data and save the edited data back into the database but I also need to be able to assign colours to individual cells and borders to make it look more user-friendly. Also I prefer a click-and-edit way of editing the table contents.

I already tried using the DataGridView but it fell short on customizing it's appearance.

Is there another good .net component I can make use of to achieve this?

---

EDIT: It's a windows Forms desktop application.

Comment: Is this a desktop or web application? There are toolkits and components available, but are usually specific to the type of environment and I'd hate to suggest the wrong one.

Comment: ...and if you are using desktop, what are you using, wpf or winforms?

Comment: This is a desktop application. Also it runs on a single desktop only.

Comment: The DataGridView is the ideal component for what you want.  In what way(s) was it inadequate for what you want?

Comment: It was indeed ideal for gathering and editing the information.
But I need two things:
- retrieving data, editing and posting it back. (this isn't the real problem)
- A table component that has more option in how the table looks (flexible UI Options)

I think the second one is the harder part in this question. since (I believe) all tables are capable of holding the information in the correct way (note that I am only using textfields).

Comment: You can set styles down to the individual cell level in a datagrid, but you have to do it at run time if it is not a global style.  In other words, subscribe to the cell formatting event (or a similar event) and set the cell's individual style based on the data at hand (i.e. making a cell background red if the value is above some level).

Additionally, if your underlying data storage containing implements IBIndingList and INotifyPropertyChanged, it will assist you in keeping your data in-sync between datagrid, memory, and database

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with those functions though, I managed to get the grid color and header backgrounds but nothing else.

Can you (or anyone else) provide me with an example on how to achieve these custom cells? google hasn't been much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CellFormatting event to change individual cells when binding them to the datagrid

example from my own code:

```
private void dgColorCodeKey_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{  
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        //if we are binding a cell in the Color column
        if (e.ColumnIndex == colColor.Index)
        {
            //ColorCode is a custom object that contains the name of a System.Drawing.Color
        ColorCode bindingObject = (ColorCode)dgColorCodeKey.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        dgColorCodeKey[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.FromName(bindingObject.Color);

        //set this property to true to tell the datagrid that we've applied our own formatting
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, see this [Data Grid FAQ](http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc) for a really good, clear description of how a datagrid works and what various methods and events do.